# Autorefresh div with javascript

Tags: javascript, reload

I have been looking around for the simplest way to refresh a particular div on my page, automatically, every x seconds.

So far I've got:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = startInterval;
function startInterval()
{
    setInterval("startTime();",1000);
}

function startTime()
{
    document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = Date();
}
```

However the last part where the innerHTML is set to the date function is what I'd like replaced by the content of the "time" ID, and not an actual date print.

I know I could load an iframe, or externa html page, but I would like to simply call upon an existing div on the page instead of having to change the existing content. Is that possible?

Thanks!

Edit: What I mean is I have a a div that looks like this on the page:

Some stuff

I would like to have that div refreshed every x seconds, so yes, you may ignore the Date() part of my example, I simply found that code as is but when I tried to remove the .innerHTML part it just does nothing, I think lol!

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "call upon an existing div on the page" ?

Comment: Wait, you want to replace the content of the `#time` with the content of the `#time`?

Comment: First of all you should prefer `setInterval(startTime,1000);` syntax. Can you clarify *I'd like replaced by the content of the "time" ID, and not an actual date print.* - I am afraid I don't understand.

Comment: I think the OP wants to refresh what's in `#time`, so "ignore `Date()`". This will probably involve AJAX IMO.

Comment: Edited my initial post, sorry about the lack of clarity. @JaredFarrish you are correct, I want to refresh the content of the #time div. Is AJAX the only way?

Comment: Take a look at XMLHttpRequest. MDN tutorial: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_XMLHttpRequest

Comment: To answer your comment, no, not necessarily. You mentioned iframe's, that's one (non-simple) way. You could also use a `script` tag and refresh the script tag. AJAX is pretty standard, though, so I would look into that.

Comment: Note, before this gets brought into it, you can use a framework like [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/), which can greatly simplify AJAX methods across browsers and in practice. However, it's not required and for simple scripts, just using a simple cross-browser script could work just fine. In other words, if the only reason you use jQuery is for `$.ajax()` *just this one time*, maybe consider that's overkill, but if you need it for other things, it's a very well established framework. There are others, of course.

Comment: Thanks @JaredFarrish . I'm afraid I'll have to rely to iframes, even though they are awful to maintain. I am simply not sufficiently knowledgeable in ajax or XML to decipher any of that in the short amount of time I have. If you could kindly expand on the .ajax() method, that might be an option I can use as I've tampered a bit with jQuery and it's present on the site for many other reasons!

Comment: What about this script tag you mentionned? The purpose of this is actually to refresh a div that contains nothing but a script tag, for advertising. If there's a specific method for this, it might be ideal!

Comment: There's [`$.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/), [`$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/), and [`$.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/).

Comment: So in the end there is no way around having to move my content in an external file and then loading it back into the div?

Comment: Using jQuery, it's really not that hard. Here's a demo (using jsfiddle's `echo/html/` that shows a short piece of how it could work: http://jsfiddle.net/Ah3jS/). If you want to use a script, you just need to reload the `script` tag by modifying it's `src`. Some people just capture it and append a different value, ie a random number, to the url before refreshing. Something to tell the browser to reload the `script` url.

Comment: That example right there seems fantastic, lemme try! Thanks for all your suggestions by the way :)

Comment: Hmm on second look, it does exactly what I don't want; it uses an external html. Thanks anyhow, but I really was trying to avoid using any external files and simply reload what is already on the site!

Comment: So you're looking for in-place "reloading" to rerun a script that's not encapsulated? (For instance, in a `function` that can be called again.) This limits your options. You can try to get a `script` tag's contents and inject it into a `function` you create (so you can recall the `function` just by calling it). It's not simple to recall a `script`, though. You can try the `script` element `src` reload, or load it yourself into a JS variable and `eval()` it (not recommended).

Comment: Also, for security reasons jQuery limits loading scripts in AJAX, so that can be problematic to work with. It would really be better to simply find what element needs to be reloaded. Hopefully this doesn't involve gaming an ad service, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTE:** The OP is actually wanting to reload a script in an ad service already included on the page. The following does not help with this; however, due to the way the question was asked, I'm leaving this answer since I think it could help others looking for the following type of solution. Just be aware this does not demonstrate how to "rerun" already included (presumably global and non-function'd) code.

---

Say I have the following `div` I'd like to dynamically refresh:

```
<div id="refresh">Refreshes...</div>
```

jQuery offers the [`$.ajax` group of functions](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) that allow you to dynamically request a page and use the response as HTML. For instance:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $refresh = $('#refresh'),
        loaded = 1,
        data = {
            html: $.toJSON({
                text: 'some text',
                object: {}
            }),
            delay: 3
        };

    var refresh = function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "/echo/html/",
            data: data,
            type: "GET",
            success: function(response) {
                $refresh.html($refresh.html() + '<br/>#' + loaded);
                loaded++;
                setTimeout(refresh, 3000);
            }
        });
    };

    refresh();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ah3jS/

Note, I'm using jsFiddle's [`echo/html/`](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html) functionality here as well. The `data` variable is tuned to working with this for demonstration purposes. In reality, the `data` sent with the request is either `GET` or `POST` variables like you work with normally. Also, I *don't* use `response` in `success`, but that's because it doesn't return anything in jsFiddle's demo mode.

jQuery make's this stuff pretty easy. Really, I'd think about using it instead of most other approaches (requirements notwithstanding).

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your help and taking the time to explain this in details. I must admit I ended up using iframes, it does what I need, although not so clean. Thanks for your time anyhow!

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = startInterval;
function startInterval() {
    setInterval("startTime();",1000);
}

function startTime() {
    var now = new Date();
    document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = now.getHours() + ":" + now.getMinutes() + ":" +now.getSeconds();
}
</script>
```